# Como obtener una respuesta usando ngResource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo un *controller* con el que pude (*por fin*), guardar un registro en mi base de datos, que es este:

```
  function PuestoAddController(puestosService, puesto){
    var self = this;
    var _puesto = puesto;

    function _add(_puesto){
      console.log("Puesto: " + _puesto.clave + " - " + _puesto.nombre + " - " + _puesto.orden);
      puestosService.save(_puesto, function(){
        console.log('Registro Guardado');
      });
    }

    self.add = _add;
  }
```

Esto funciona como se espera, pero necesito obtener la respuesta del servidor, por ejemplo, si fue exitoso, obtengo el código `201`, pero puede ser un mensaje de error del tipo `Esta clave ya está registrada`.

A partir de la respuesta recibida, programaré las acciones que sean necesarias, por ejemplo, limpiar el formulario, mandar a otra página, etc.

Mi servicio es este:

```
(function(angular){
  'use strict';

  angular.module('cmi')
    .factory('puestosService', PuestosService);

  PuestosService.$inject = ['$resource', 'config', 'session'];

  function PuestosService($resource, config, session){
    var puestosURL = config.baseURL + config.apiURL + '/capine/puesto/:id/';
    return $resource(
      puestosURL,
      {id: '@id'},
      {
        'get': {cache: true, isArray: false},
        'query': {method:'GET', isArray: true, cache: true},
        'save': {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {'Authorization': 'Token '+ session.getAccessToken()}
        }
      }
    );
  }
})(angular);
```

> En la [documentación del módulo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) existe una acción que se llama `transformResponse`, pero desafortunadamente no ofrecen ningún ejemplo de uso.

### Pregunta

¿Como puedo obtener la respuesta del servidor RESTful si utilizo ngResource (`$resource`) en AngularJS 1.x?

Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: aqui hay un ejemplo http://jsfiddle.net/roadprophet/prtap/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Otra manera de hacerlo es usando la propiedad `$promise`, por ejemplo:

```
puestosService.save(_puesto).$promise
  .then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Cuando uso `$promise` el servidor responde con el código `400 (Bad Request)`, lo que deja `response` sin definir.

Comment: Por lo general un error `400 (Bad Request)` significa que el API no recibió los parámetros en el formato esperado, verifica eso.

Comment: En caso de un http status diferente de `2xx`, el servicio `$http` de angular rechaza la promesa, por lo que nunca entra en el bloque `.then` sino en el `.catch``

Comment: Creo que tienes razón... voy a borrar mis registros y empezar de nuevo...